# Angular velocity: $\omega = vr$ or $\omega = v/r$?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, angular-velocity

Which one is the formula of angular velocity? Is it $\omega= vr$? If not then why does the source below use $mvr=nh/2\pi$, where $mvr$ is angular momentum and $vr$ is angular velocity? Again $\omega=v/r$ shows radian per second. I saw $\omega= vr$ in one book and $\omega= v/r$ in another!

> [image]
>
> [image]